# how to set a variable using before:run function in cypress before running all specs?

Tags: cypress

I want to set the variable before running any spec. For that, I am using the [before:run](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/before-run-api) function. I have set [experimentalInteractiveRunEvents](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Experiments) to `true` in the `cypress.config.js` file.

But when I run the code and try to print that variable in a spec file it is not giving me any value.

The error I got is:

[image]

How do I set a variable in cypress `before:run` function?

Answer (score 4):

The line `Cypress.env()` cannot be used in `cypress.config.js` as the error message states, but the `config` parameter provided to `setupNodeEvents` is equivalent.

You must **return the modified config** on the last line of `setupNodeEvents`.

#### cypress.config.js

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress'

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      config.env = {
        ...config.env,
        token
      }
      return config
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have tried the same approach you mentioned but I am still not getting variable values in my spec file. on("before:run", 
    details => {
    //regionName = 'AutomationRegion'
    // config.env = {
    //   ...config.env,
    //   regionName
    // }

    regionName = "test";

    console.log(regionName, details.config);
    details.config.env = {
      ...details.config.env,
      regionName
    }
    
    return details.config;
  })
  //return config;
};

Comment: Cheers, I agree it's pretty easy when you think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Cypress commands cannot be used anywhere inside the plugin/index.js. If any env variables should be set, you have few options

1. Create a command.js file under the support folder that includes before() block. This will run before all the tests. As this is part of the test, you can use Cypress.env function

   ```
   before(() => {
     Cypress.env("token", <token_value>);
   });
   ```
2. Set the environment variable in the plugin/index.js file modifying the config variable as follows:

   ```
   module.exports = ( on, config ) => {
    config.env.token = <token_value>

    ...

   });
   ```